# Cannot select the whole stack when selecting the second stack on mouseover

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a divergent bar chart, which shows the buy and sell volume on a particular date.

[image]

The graph has both zoom and brush working on it. I am having trouble selecting the whole bar when hovering/clicking on the orange(Sell) color bar, the Blue(Buy) color bar works on mouseover and click. I have created same class name for a stack but when I try to select the lower stack the stroke width does not change and same is the case with click. In both the functions, upper bar works but not the lower one. Also any suggestion on how to deactivate the click when an event is made on the body of the svg would be appreciated.

working image :

[image]

Problem:

[image]

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/uLn7v426/) is the code for the chart

```
<!DOCtyPE html>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

                <style type="text/css">

                        body {
                                font-family: avenir next, sans-serif;
                                font-size: 12px;
                        }

                .zoom {
                        cursor: move;
                        fill: none;
                        pointer-events: all;
                }



                #tooltip {
                background-color: rgba(187, 187, 187, 0.7);
                border-radius: 5px;
                height: 18px;
                opacity: 0;
                pointer-events: none;
                position: absolute;
                text-align: center;
                }

</style>

        <body>
        </body>

        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/d3fc@13.0.1"></script>
                <script>

           function randomData(samples) {
                    var data = [],
                        random = d3.randomNormal();

                    for (i = 0; i < samples; i++) {
                        data.push({
                            Buy: Math.floor(Math.abs(Math.random()*1000000)),
                            Sell: Math.floor(Math.abs(Math.random()*1000000)),
                            Date: new Date(2013,01,i)
                        });
                    }
                    return data;
                }



                var data = randomData(100)


                data.forEach(d => {
                        d["Date"] = new Date(d["Date"]);
                        d["Buy"] = +d["Buy"];
                        d["Sell"] = +d["Sell"]*(-1);
                })


                var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 230, left: 70},
                margin2 = {top: 250, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
                width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
                height = 900 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
                height2 = 350 - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;


                var series = d3.stack()
                .keys(["Buy", "Sell"])
                .offset(d3.stackOffsetDiverging)
                (data);    
                console.log(series)

                var Ctx = d3.scaleTime().rangeRound([0, width]),
                x = fc.scaleDiscontinuous(d3.scaleTime().rangeRound([0, width])).discontinuityProvider(fc.discontinuitySkipWeekends()), 
                y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height ,0]),
                Cty = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height2, 0]),
                x3 = d3.scaleTime().rangeRound([0, width]);


                x.domain(d3.extent(data,function(d) { return d["Date"]; }))
                y.domain([d3.min(series, stackMin), d3.max(series, stackMax)])
                Ctx.domain(x.domain());
                Cty.domain(y.domain());

                let formatValue = d3.format(".2s");

                function stackMin(serie) {
                        return d3.min(serie, function(d) { return d[0]; });
                }

                function stackMax(serie) {
                        return d3.max(serie, function(d) { return d[1]; });
                }

                var z = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10)

                var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).tickSize(0),
                xAxis3 = d3.axisBottom(x3).ticks(0).tickSize(0),
                xAxis2 = d3.axisBottom(Ctx).tickSize(0),
                yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).tickFormat(function(d) { return formatValue(d).replace('G', 'B');});

                var brush = d3.brushX()
                .extent([[0, 0], [width, height2]])
                .on("brush", brushed);

                var zoom = d3.zoom()
                .scaleExtent([1, 50])
                .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
                .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
                .on("zoom", zoomed);

                var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

                svg.append("rect")
                .attr("class", "zoom")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height)
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
                .call(zoom);

                svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
                .attr("id", "clip")
                .append("rect")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height);

                var focus = svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "focus")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

                var context = svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "context")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + (height+80)+ ")");


                var bars = focus.append("g");
                bars.attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
                .attr("cursor","pointer")
                .attr("height",height)
                .attr("width",width);

                focus
                  .append("g")
                  .attr("class", "axis x-axis")
                  .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height+5})`)
                  .call(xAxis);

                focus.append("g")
                .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
                .call(yAxis);

                bars.selectAll("g")
                .data(series)
                .enter().append("g")
                .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key) })
                .selectAll("rect")      
                .data(function(d) { return d; })
                .enter().append("rect")
                .attr('class', (d, i) => `bar bar-${i}`)
                .transition()
                .duration(1000)
                .attr("width",10)
                .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.data["Date"])})
                .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1])})
                .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1])});

                var toggleSelected = true;
                focus.selectAll(".bar")
                .on('mouseover', function (d, i, elements) {
                        d3.selectAll(`.bar-${i}`)
                        .style('stroke', 'black')
                        .style('stroke-width', '2')
                        tooltip.transition()
                        .duration(100)
                        .style('opacity', .9);
                        tooltip.text((d3.select(this)))
                        .style('left', `${d3.event.pageX + 2}px`)
                        .style('top', `${d3.event.pageY - 18}px`);

                })
                .on('mouseout', function (d, i, elements) {
                        d3.selectAll(`.bar-${i}`)
                        .style('stroke', 'none')
                        .style('stroke-width', '0')
                        tooltip.transition()
                        .duration(400)
                        .style('opacity', 0);       
//                        
                })
                .on("click",function (d, i, elements) {

                        if(toggleSelected == true) {
                                d3.selectAll(`.bar:not(.bar-${i})`)
                                .style("opacity",0.2)
                                toggleSelected = false;
                        } else {
                                d3.selectAll(`.bar`)
                                .style("opacity",1)
                                toggleSelected = true;
                        } 

                })

                var bars = context.append("g");
                bars.attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");
                bars.selectAll("bar")
                .data(series)
                .enter().append("g")
                .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); })
                .selectAll("rect")
                .data(function(d) { return d; })
                .enter().append("rect")
                .attr('class', 'barContext')
                .attr("width",5)
                .attr("x", function(d) { return Ctx(d.data["Date"])})
                .attr("y", function(d) { return Cty(d[1])})
                .attr("height", function(d) { return Cty(d[0]) - Cty(d[1])})


                context.append("g")
                .attr("class", "axis x-axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
                .call(xAxis2);

                context.append("g")
                .attr("class", "brush")
                .call(brush)
                .call(brush.move, x.range());



                function brushed() {
                        if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "zoom") return; // ignore brush-by-zoom
                        var s = d3.event.selection 
                        x.domain(s.map(Ctx.invert, Ctx));
                        let max = 0, min = 0, valueX =0,valueY=0;

                        series.map((stack, i) => {
                            stack.filter(el => el.data.Date >= x.domain()[0] && el.data.Date <= x.domain()[1])
                            .forEach(el => {
                                valueX = Math.max(valueX,y(el.data["Buy"]))
                                valueY = Math.min(valueY,y(el.data["Buy"]))
                                max = Math.max(max, el.data["Buy"])
                                min = Math.min(min, el.data["Sell"])
                            });
                        });

                    valueY= Math.abs(valueY)
                    value = valueX > valueY ? valueX : valueY;

                    value = Math.floor(value)
                        y.domain([min,max])


                        var tran = svg.transition().duration(350);
                    if ((s[1]-s[0])>10)
                    {
                        focus.selectAll(".bar") 
                        .transition().duration(200)
                        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.data["Date"])})
                        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1])})
                        .attr("width",20)
                         .attr("height", function(d) {


                            return (y(d[0]) - y(d[1]))});

                        focus.select(".x-axis").transition(tran).call(xAxis);
                        focus.select(".axis--y").transition(tran).call(yAxis);
                        svg.select(".zoom")
                            .call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity.scale(width / (s[1] - s[0])).translate(-s[0], 0));
}

                }

                function zoomed() {
                        if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "brush") return; // ignore zoom-by-brush
                        var t = d3.event.transform;
                        x.domain(t.rescaleX(Ctx).domain());
                        var previousy = y.domain()
                        let max = 0, min = 0,valueX=0,valueY=0;
                        series.map((stack, i) => {
                            stack.filter(el => el.data.Date >= x.domain()[0] && el.data.Date <= x.domain()[1])
                            .forEach(el => {
                                max = Math.max(max, el.data["Buy"])
                                min = Math.min(min, el.data["Sell"])

                            });
                        });
                        var tran = svg.transition().duration(350);
                        y.domain([min,max])



                    focus.selectAll(".bar")
                            .transition().duration(200)
                            .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.data["Date"])})
                            .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1])})
                            .attr("width",20)
                            .attr("height", function(d) { return (y(d[0]) - y(d[1]))});

                    focus.select(".x-axis").transition(tran).call(xAxis)
                    focus.select(".axis--y").transition(tran).call(yAxis);
                    context.select(".brush").call(brush.move, x.range().map(t.invertX, t))


        };


        </script>
```

Comment: Is my solution what you need? Maybe, I incorrect understand your question.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thank you. Could you please tell me how to deactivate the click when I click on the white space of the graph. Currently the click deactivates only when I click on bars.

Comment: Yes, you should specify click handler for `svg` element. I updated the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/tcg3r04f/3/ check it. See strings 136-143.

Comment: Thank you. Can you also tell me how to set the initial brush to latest 3 months. I mean like when the graph loads it should show the latest 3 months data.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not ideas how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this code:

```
...
.on("click",function (d, i, elements) {
        if(toggleSelected == true) {
                d3.selectAll(`.bar:not(.bar-${i})`)
                .style("opacity",0.2)
                toggleSelected = false;
        } else {
                d3.selectAll(`.bar`)
                .style("opacity",1)
                toggleSelected = true;
        } 

})
...
```

When you click on orange rect, argument `i` it is the length of all blue rects + index of clicked orange rect.

You can get appropriate index, for example, from `class` attribute this way:

```
.on("click",function (d, i, elements) {
        var index = parseInt(this.getAttribute('class').replace('bar bar-', ''), 10);

        if(toggleSelected == true) {
                d3.selectAll(`.bar:not(.bar-${index})`)
                .style("opacity",0.2)
                toggleSelected = false;
        } else {
                d3.selectAll(`.bar`)
                .style("opacity",1)
                toggleSelected = true;
        } 

})
```

Absolutely the same problem for `mouseover` and `mouseout` event-handlers. Look at my fork of your fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/tcg3r04f/3/

Comment: I am trying to integrate this chart with my react application. When I try to add this line it throw me an error.   `var index = parseInt(this.getAttribute('class').replace('bar bar-', ''), 10)` . `getAttribute is not a function`. How do I use `this` in react. when I `consolelog(this)` it is not selecting the element.

Comment: Do you use arrow function `.on("click, () => {...`? If you use arrow function this error can appear, because of arrow function do not create own scope. Change arrow function on standard function in this case. `.on("click, function () => {...`.